# How to remove the Na values from a stack of rasters?

Tags: raster, r, nodata, stack

In R I have a stack (nsw.stack) which contains 6 variables. I have clipped the extent. However, When I look at the summary it appears that there is a lot of NA values (see below). I **think** this is slowing down the computing power when i do a raster prediction. (right?)

If so, how do I get rid of the NA.values from the rasters prior to using the predict code, or is there a way to ignore the NA values while predicting.

```
> summary(nsw.stack)
                 riv         lake         ndvi    temp    prec     dem
Min.    0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00      -0.0960     -14     114      -4
1st Qu. 2.640341e-02 7.969768e-02       0.2328      29     162     134
Median  7.040909e-02 1.814401e-01       0.3288      49     219     226
3rd Qu. 1.814401e-01 3.925149e-01       0.4128      75     297     338
Max.    1.120824e+00 1.613323e+00       0.7176     115     406    1281
NA's    2.103107e+06 2.103674e+06 2103309.0000 2103188 2103188 2103188
Warning message:
In .local(object, ...) :
  summary is an estimate based on a sample of 1e+05 cells (2.47% of all cells)
```

Comment: Turns out you are not meant to remove the NA's. You need them in this situation.

Answer (score 3):

If you have NA values that indicates that for a given raster they may not have a value at that particular location. There is a very thorough answer here on the [topic](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/220002/19042) You may want to ensure that you have cropped and masked your rasters before doing any future analysis. In R, you can change the NA values to a value to visualize where these NA values are and what could be going on with your data. If you choose, you could also remove them. There's another great example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11966967/2479601) with visualization of NA values.

```
nsw.stack[is.na(nsw.stack)] <- 999
```

Answer (score 0):

The `raster` package function `predict()` has an `na.rm` option. I think that would be the best way to address this problem.